Airflow GlueJob operator creating Python2 jobs
I'm trying to run a Glue Job from Apache Airflow with the following code:
with TaskGroup(group_id= DAG_NAME + '_group', dag=dag) as tg:
    for job in jobs_params:

        glue = GlueJobOperator(
            task_id=f'run_{job["name"]}',
            job_name=job["name"],
            script_location=job["script_location"],
            script_args=job["script_args"],
            aws_conn_id='glue_job_conn',
            region_name='us-east-1',
            iam_role_name="AWSGlueServiceRoleReadS3",
            create_job_kwargs={"Command": {"PythonVersion": "3"},
                                "GlueVersion": "4.0", "WorkerType": "G.1X", "NumberOfWorkers": 2},
            deferrable=False,
            verbose=True,
            
            dag=dag,
        )  

I've tried everything but I keep getting the following error:
LAUNCH ERROR | Python 2 is not supported with this glue versionPlease refer logs for details.

What am I missing? I don't understand why it's trying to create a job with Python2 in the first place. But even using create_job_kwargs the problem is not solved.

so, I found out what happend: when you create a Glue Job for the first time, rerunning the DAG doesn't "overwrite" it. Then, as I have run the DAG for the first time without the arguments
create_job_kwargs={"Command": {"Name":"glueetl", "PythonVersion": "3", "ScriptLocation": job["script_location"]},
                            "GlueVersion": "4.0", "WorkerType": "G.1X", "NumberOfWorkers": 2}.

it created a GlueJob with Python 2. I had to delete the Jobs and rerun the DAG with the correct arguments and it worked!
